# iOS BLE Error Reading Characteristic: Reading is not permitted

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

I have a ble device that I can connect to, but the problem is that I cannot read the characteristics from it.

Here is the process:

1. Scanning the device = OK
2. Peripheral is discoverable = OK
3. Connection = OK
4. Request all the characteristics available in each services = NOT OK

This code returns error: "Reading is not permitted."

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering services: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
codes......
}
```

The weird part is that in android's case, they can read the characteristics but in iOS it cannot.

Before I argue with the platform guys who handles the device, I just wanna make sure if this is error is on app side or the device side? Can anyone explain to me? Thank you vm.

Comment: The first thing I would try is the LightBlue app from the app store; If it can see your characteristics then you have an error;  if it can't then the problem is probably with the device.